# Log4net RollingFileAppender filename just with datetime

Tags: log4net

With the config:

```
<file value="C:\\MyLog"/> 
<datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'.log'" />
```

I can get the historical log named like "**Mylog20120529.log**".

I wonder whether i can get the log named like "**20120529.log**".

THX guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apply a trick here and it will do the job.

```
<file value="C:\\MyLog\20"/> 
<datePattern value="yyMMdd'.log'" />
```